# Are same interval leaps consented in second species counterpoint?

Tags: intervals, counterpoint

I've been told that, in second species counterpoint, presenting the same interval in 2 consecutive bars is an error. What then if the intervals skips in opposite directions?

Like this:

[image]

Is this considered an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, from what I can tell everything is correct here - the only downside being that you have octaves beginning each measure, which makes counterpoint stagnant.  You always want to aim for imperfect consonances (3's or 6's) for your downbeats.

That said, you've approached the octave correctly (contrary motion with one voice moving by step), and the two skips are connected by a step with the second skip filling in the note previously skipped.

Keep in mind that my comments are made in the vein of strict Baroque counterpoint.  If you were to fast-foward 150 years and do these same exercises with functional harmony, two skips in a row would be acceptable in controlled circumstances...so everything is relative.

Good question!